# After Disposing HwndSource calling close() on window leads to System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf

I am calling `new Window1().ShowDialog();` from MainWindow when Dispose() is called on HwndSource calling this.close() on Window arise `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
What if i don't call Dispose, is there any problem may occurs in the future.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private const int MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK = 0x0400 + 6;
    private HwndSource source;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Closing += Window_Closing;
    }
    private void Close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => this.Close();

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        var FormHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(FormHandle);
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // Handle messages...
        if (msg == MESSAGE_CAPTURED_OK)
        {
            // operations
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        source.RemoveHook(WndProc);
        //source.Dispose(); This line rises error
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it WPF or WinUI? You shouldn't mix tags

Comment: It is WPF, i removed WinUI tag.

Comment: What is not obvious that WindowInteropHelper.Handle returns the WPF window handle.  And HwndSource.FromHwnd() returns the WPF source.  So in effect the Dispose() call kills the WPF window, in this case a bit earlier than it normally would since the code uses the Closing event.  No, don't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoDialogHide() seems to get upset with the dispose.

Doing this will correct the problem

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    source.RemoveHook(WndProc);
    source.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to answer my question.

Comment: No worries. Check this out for more information. https://issuehint.com/issue/dotnet/wpf/6757